# Single websocket connection to use across components and store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, mobx

I have a mobx store which stores all the data from the server.

// stores.js

```
class User {
    @observable userInfo = null;
    @observable webSocketConnected = false;
}

class Trend {
    @observable latest_trends = null;
}
```

I have a component to type and send user input to the server via websockets.

```
@inject('UserStore') @observer
export default class Editor extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        socket = new WebSocket(newURL);
    }

    sendText = () => {
        // socket.send(...) and update to the store
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                ...
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.text}
                    ...
                    style={styles.text}/>
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

I have another component that can vote a user's comment, which I would like to update to the server via websockets.

```
@inject('TrendStore') @observer
export default class Editor extends React.Component {
    updateComment = () => {
        // socket.send(...)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updateComment}>
                <Icon/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I create one WebSocket connection, so that I can use it with all my store and components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would create a websocket service class that gets passed to the constructor of every store, that needs access to the websocket. In your program's main file you initialize all stores and provide them to the  component.

```
const webSocketService = new WebSocketService();
const userstore = new UserStore(websocketService);
const trendStore = new TrendStore(websocketservice);
const stores = { userStore, trendStore };
...
<Provider {...stores} >
   ...
</Provider>
```

The WebSocketService can have methods like

- send(message)
- registerEventListener(event, listener)

So you are giving every store the same instance of websocketService.

Tip: don't write your sending logic or any other business login in the components. Add a method to the specific store like *sendMessage(message)* and call this method from your component.

Hope this answers your question.